# css issue in aligning 3 block equally spaced box

Tags: html, css

I have a template which has 3 equally spaced boxes, the problem is that i am unable to get the last box to align correctly the first two elements.

how do i add a 3 block equally spaced box in css without tables?

my attempt http://khine.3b1.org/activities/activities.html

any advise much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get them all into one column?

Comment: no, i am trying to get them all on one horizontal row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all three boxes float left:

```
.box ul.supports-list li.last {
 width: 200px;
 position: relative;
 float: left;
}
```

And provide more width overall:

```
.box .holder .frame {
  background: url(./box-b.gif) no-repeat 0 100%;
  width: 620px;
  padding: 18px 4px 42px 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the next CSS rules to:

```
.box ul.supports-list {
    font-size: 11px;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 7px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.box ul.supports-list li.supports-list-item {
    display: list-item;
    float: left;
    outline-style: none;
    width: 200px;
}

.box ul.supports-list li.last {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i was looking to have this as one row not one column

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to put each box into a div, and then adjust each div's `margin-left` and `margin-top` properties to get them to all line up. You'd also want to set the `float` property of all of the boxes to `left`. It might not be the most-widely-accepted way of doing things, but that's how I usually solve problems like this.

You can take a look at this example jsFiddle I did for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cwca22/g8x5E/ - Hope this helps!